# Best Django model field to store frequency (from Hz to 10 GHz)

Tags: django, postgresql

What is the best model field to store a frequency, from 1 Hz to 10 GHz?
IMHO could be a `PositiveBigIntegerField` but I'm not completely convinced...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need integer hertzes, then go with PositiveBigIntegerField, nothing wrong with that.

If you (think you might) need non-integer values, you could store eg. millihertzes - or just go for a DecimalField and store hertz.

Comment: My context is radio frequencies, so I could have values like 446.083.300 Hz that I think to represent as 446.083,3 MHz in the frontend... I think store as integers is ok (I prefer to decimalfield, maybe is just suggestion but integers seems easier)